# include php file in echo html code

Tags: php, php-include

I cant get this syntax to work, already tried modifying it many time.

```
    <?php
echo 
"<a href='".include 'go/randomlink.php'."'>".$item['stockid']."</a>";
?>
```

Comment: does your include file returns something?

Comment: randomlink.php generates a randomlink from a list, which I want to include

Comment: Please, read examle 5 here http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, your other php file must simply echo some string.

randomlink.php:

```
<?php
echo "What came first the chicken or the egg?";
?>
```

index.php:

```
echo "<a href='";
include('go/randomlink.php');
echo "'>" . $item['stockid'] . "</a>";
```

hope this helps you.